# ¿Cómo capturar el nombre de un servidor sea local o web en una variable con JS?

Tags: javascript, url

Tengo un problema y es el siguiente, para hacer una validación con javascript debo de hacer lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
       url:http://localhost/School/Students),
      type: POST
})
```

podría poner algo como esto:

```
$.ajax({
       url:../School/Students),
      type: POST
})
```

Pero no me funciona, debo de poner una url fija para que haga el trabajo bien.

Mi problema ahora es que necesito subir este proyecto a un servidor y si uso esta `url:http://localhost/School/Students` no me va a funcionar.

Posiblemente la respuesta va a ser *¿Y porque no cambias el nombre del servidor local (localhost) por el nombre del servidor web?.*

El motivo es que hay muchas funciones dentro del *js* que están trabajando con una url fija es por ese motivo que busco la posibilidad de trabajar con una variable "**dinámica**" independiente del tipo de servidor que sea.

**un ejemplo mas claro seria algo como esto**

- http://localhost/School/Students
- http://58952server/School/Students
- http://es.nombreservidor/School/Students
- http://otroejemplo/School/Students

Osea la idea es que el JS se adapte al nombre del servidor que sea para que funcione de la manera correcta y haga las validaciones de forma correcta.

Agradezco el interés.

Comment: ¿Qué causa que el dominio del servidor cambie?

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes colocar en el parámetro **url** el valor del enlace de la siguiente manera '/School/Students/'.

Tu función debe quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
       url:'/School/Students/',
      type: POST
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, tienes un error de sintaxis, lo correcto es:

```
  url:"http://localhost/School/Students"
```

Después, para obtener la `url` actual(completa incluyendo las variables por GET), independientemente de si es un proyecto local o lo que sea utiliza:

```
window.location.href
```

Si quieres obtener la ruta padre utiliza el [objeto Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location):

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/School/Students'
```

donde location.host es la ruta de tu sitio(que se adapta a cualquier url), en estos casos:

- http://localhost/School/Students
- http://58952server/School/Students
- http://es.nombreservidor/School/Students
- http://otroejemplo/School/Students

y con esto puedes construir la ruta a los folders de manera estática sin conflicto con el nombre de dominio.

Comment: que pena @Rene Limon depronto no fui claro con el problema que tenga y me excuso, yo no necesito redireccionamiento yo necesito es cambiar el localhost.

Comment: creo que la respuesta que te dí también sirve para lo que quieres hacer, ya que si vas a cambiar de dominio y quieres que las rutas absolutas cambien a dinamicas puedes usar el Location Object